# NUnit tests are not recognized in Visual Studio express 2015?

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-2015, nunit

I am writing tests with NUnit , but tests are not recognized by Test explorer window. I did following steps ,

1) Added Project

2) Added NuGet - NUnit , NUnitTestAdapter and Selenium ,chrome

3) Added following code

```
 IWebDriver driver = null;

    [SetUp]
    public void Initilize()
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        driver.Url = "http://www.google.com";
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void Close()
    {
        driver.Close();
    }
```

I did build , Nothing is showing in Test Explorer , please help me in this situation, is it need special license for Test or I am doing wrong .

Comment: Which NUnit version are you using? NUnit3 versions require NUnit3 Test Adapter

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I am using NUnit 3.5.0 and NUnitTestAdapter 2.0.0   , after your comment  I added "NUnit3TestAdapter" , but still test are not displaying in test explorer .

Comment: Did you *remove* NUnitTestAdapter 2 ? VS won't use both of them.

Comment: BTW [Express doesn't allow any extensions](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-express/). Are you referring to VS Community perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Yes I removed already .

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Yes I am using Visual Studio Express 2015 , what you mean "Express doesn't allow any extensions." , I am using NUget , I haven't added extension , please   correct me if I am wrong .